# CSV dataset to text dataset

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, csv

I have a csv dataset student.csv with 1000 rows and 10 columns.

The sample data looks like this:

```
s_id,s_name,s_dob,s_class,s_marks,s_parentname,
   1,abc,1/1/18,5,49,def,
   2,xyz,1/1/17,4,85,abc,
   3,pqr,1/2/18,2,78,mnp,
```

From this dataset, I want to copy all the dates that have 'abc' in their rows to a text file.

Expected output:

```
text.txt
1/1/18
1/1/17
```

Comment: If `abcd` exists in a row does that satisfy your `abc` exists criteria or not? In other words are you looking for full matches on a field or partial matches?

Comment: No, it doesn't satisfy. Looking for full matches not partial matches. Thanka @EdMorton.

Comment: You're welcome. OK, I added an answer given that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep abc student.csv | cut -d, -f 3 >text.txt
```

This would first extract every line from `student.csv` that contains the substring `abc` anywhere, and then cut out the 3rd comma-delimited column from those lines and store them in `text.txt`.

With the data given in the question, `text.txt` would end up containing

```
1/1/18
1/1/17
```

This relies on the original file being a *simple* CSV file, i.e. without fields containing embedded commas or newlines.

Would you want to search for `abc` as a *complete word*, then use `grep -w abc` in place of just `grep abc`.  This would avoid matching lines containing strings like `abcde`, but would still match a field containing `abc xyz`.

If you are looking for fields that contain an arbitrary complex string (still in a simple CSV file) and if you need the field to be exactly equal to that string, then you would have to iterate over the fields on each line:

```
string='some string' awk -F, '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i == ENVIRON["string"]) { print $3 ; next } }' student.csv
```

This `awk` code iterates over all fields on each line looking for a comma-delimited field whose value is exactly the same as the value of the environment variable `string`. Once such a field is found, the 3rd field is printed.

Comment: Hey @Kusalananda, Thanks for the answer. It works. Thanks a  lot for the effort.

Comment: Can I get any suggestion on how to copy the s_marks column which have abc in their row and have an s_marks value above 15 to a text file along with headers. Please note that, the s_marks values should be sorted and printed in a text file. Thanks in advance @Kusalananda

Answer (score 1):

using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) starting from

```
s_id,s_name,s_dob,s_class,s_marks,s_parentname,
1,abc,1/1/18,5,49,def,
2,xyz,1/1/17,4,85,abc,
3,pqr,1/2/18,2,78,mnp,
```

and running

```
mlr --nidx --fs "," filter -S '$2=="abc"' then cut -f 3 input.txt >output.txt
```

you will have

```
1/1/18
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you need full field matches:

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==1{print FILENAME} /(^|,)abc(,|$)/{print $3}' file
file
1/1/18
1/1/17
```

or if `abc` can actually contain RE metachars that you want treated literally and so you need to do a string rather than regexp match:

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==1{print FILENAME} index(","$0",",",abc,"){print $3}' file
file
1/1/18
1/1/17
```

or to print the column header:

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==1{print $3} /(^|,)abc(,|$)/{print $3}' file
s_dob
1/1/18
1/1/17

$ awk -F, 'FNR==1{print $3} index(","$0",",",abc,"){print $3}' file
s_dob
1/1/18
1/1/17
```

Comment: how can I copy the header also i.e s_dob into the output file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I updated my answer. You should show that as part of the expected output in your question.